# use the 'typename' keyword to treat nontype "pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr [with PointT=T]" as a type in a dependent contextC/C++(2675)

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I wrote two functions.

```cpp
PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr rotateCloud(PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr src);
PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>::Ptr rotateCloud(PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>::Ptr src);
```

In these two functions, I write completely same code without inside `<>`. `<PointXYZ>` or `<PointXYZRGB>`.

I want to write a single function.I heard there is Template.I tried it.

```cpp
template <typename T>
PointCloud<T>::Ptr rotateCloud(PointCloud<T>::Ptr src);
```

I got error.

```
use the 'typename' keyword to treat nontype "pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr [with PointT=T]" as a type in a dependent contextC/C++(2675)
```

I can't understand this error message.

Anyone can understand?

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `::Ptr` is a dependent type you need `typename` on the argument and return type

```
template <typename T>
typename PointCloud<T>::Ptr rotateCloud(typename PointCloud<T>::Ptr src);
```